# Creating a <div> at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know whether i can create `<div>` at runtime using JavaScript or any other method:
when clicking a button on one `<div>` another `<div>` should appear, and both `<div>`s should lay above the html page below (i.e floating `<div>`s).

Comment: Sounds like any of the lightbox-type things. You should check out jQuery IU/Dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `document.createElement("div")`. For appending it where you want it, it's `theParentElementYouWantToAppendTo.appendChild(theDivYouCreated)`.

Edit: And for the floating thing, do `theDivYouCreated.style.position = "fixed"`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

> **Overview**
>
> A dialog is a floating window that
>   contains a title bar and a content
>   area. The dialog window can be moved,
>   resized and closed with the 'x' icon
>   by default.
>
> If the content length exceeds the
>   maximum height, a scrollbar will
>   automatically appear.
>
> A bottom button bar and
>   semi-transparent modal overlay layer
>   are common options that can be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
 var ans=document.createElement('div');

 ans.setAttribute('id','kk');

 ans.setAttribute('name','jj');

 ans.setAttribute('style','display:block');

 document.getElementById('body').appendChild(ans);

 </script>
 </head>

enter code here



 <body id='body'>

 </body>

 </html>
```